# Set notation for sets produced by a sequence of Formulas.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, recurrence-relations

I have an infinite number of sets $R_1, R_2, R_3, \dots $ where $R_1 \subset R_2 \subset R_3\subset \dots$

Each set is the output (image / range) of a corresponding function:

$$R_i = Image(T_i)$$

$F_i$ has i inputs $(x_1,\dots, x_i)$ with  all inputs $x_i \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$

For a lack of a better term, the recurrence relation for the functions interpolates. Examples may be easier to understand.

$T_1(x_1) = \frac{1}{3}(2^{x_1}-1)$

$T_2(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{3}(2^{x_1}\times \frac{1}{3}(2^{x_2}-1)-1)$

$T_3(x_1,x_2,x_3) = \frac{1}{3}(2^{x_1}\times \frac{1}{3}(2^{x_2}\times \frac{1}{3}(2^{x_3}-1)-1)-1)$

Each function is a subset of the next with the last input being 2.

$T_n(x_1, \dots, x_n) = T_{n+1}(x_1,\dots,x_n,2)$

I'm after some notation that will help me probe these sets as I'm trying to find the output (range / image) of the infinite-th T $(T_\infty)$ and ideally show that $T_\infty \supset \mathbb{O}$ where $\mathbb{O}$ is the set of positive odd numbers.

Comment: Presumably, the $x_i$ range over positive integers? If they range over the whole of $[1, \infty)$, then the image of $T_1$ is the interval $[1/3, \infty)$ which already contains all odd positive integers.

Comment: Id love that to be true. What value of $x_1$ gives 3?

Comment: How about $\log_2 (10)$?

Comment: Just realised my input was continuous. It was supposed to be the integers from 1 to infinty. My mistake i'll edit thay now.

Comment: Ben: that makes more sense. I've also done an edit to clarify your notation.

Comment: Thanks @RobArthan any ideas how to solve it now?

Comment: This looks like a thinly disguised attempt to attack the [Collatz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). Am I wrong?

Comment: No disguise. Exactly what it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48040/discussion-between-ben-crossley-hobbyist-and-rob-arthan).

Comment: No. If you are working on the Collatz conjecture, I'm not interested!

Comment: Interesting response. How come?

Comment: Life is too short to collaborate with people who won't come clean about what they are working on. If you are working on the Collatz problem, then you have my best wishes, but I have no interest in collaborating with you on that work.

Comment: I'm confused. I never hid it? And openly told you when you asked.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant by "Exactly what it is". I do now.